# Interpreter-style output in Python 3 (maybe about sys.displayhook?)

Tags: python-3.x, interpreter

I'm making a little toy command window with Tk, and currently trying to make it copy some interpreter behavior.

I'd never scrutinized the interpreter before, but it's decisions on when to print a value are a little mystifying.

```
>>> 3 + 4  # implied print(...)
7
>>> 3      # implied print(...)
3
>>> a = 3  # no output, no implied print(...), bc result is None maybe?
>>> None   # no output, no print(...) implied... doesn't like None?
>>> print(None)  # but it doesn't just ban all Nones, allows explicit print()
None
>>> str(None) # unsurprising, the string 'None' is just a string, and echoed
'None'
```

The goal is to mimic this behavior, printing some Nones, not others (made slightly more complicated because I'm not entirely sure what the rules are).

So, turning to my program, I have history_text and entry_text, which are StringVar()s that control a label above an entry box in the Tk window. Then the following event is bound to the Return key, to process commands and update the history with the result.

```
def to_history(event):
    print("command entered")  # note to debugging window

    last_history = history_text.get()

    # hijack stdout
    buffer = io.StringIO('')
    sys.stdout = buffer

    # run command, output to buffer
    exec(entry_text.get())

    # buffered output to a simple string
    buffer.seek(0)
    buffer_str = ''
    for line in buffer.readlines():
        # maybe some rule goes here to decide if an implied 'print(...)' is needed
        buffer_str = buffer_str + line + '\n'

    # append typed command for echo
    new_history = entry_text.get() + '\n' + buffer_str

    # cleanup (let stdout go home)
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    buffer.close()

    history_text.set(last_history + "\n" + new_history)
    entry_text.set('')
```

As is, it does not provide any output for a simple entry of '3' or 'None' or even '3 + 4'. Adding an implied print() statement all the time seems to print too often, I don't skip the print for 'None' or 'a = 3' type statements.

I found some documentation for sys.displayhook, which seems to govern when the interpreter will actually display a result, but I'm not sure how to use it here. I thought I could just wrap sys.displayhook() around my exec() call, and have it do all this work for me... but found that it does not imply print() statements for statements like '3 + 4' or '3'.

Any suggestions? Am I on the right track with sys.displayhook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpreter prints out `repr(result)` only if `result is not None`.

There are no "implied `print`s" like you thought.

- `3 + 4` results to `7`, so `repr(7)` is printed
- `a = 3` is an assignment, I think nothing is printed because it does not work with `eval`
- `None` results to `None`, so nothing is printed
- `print(None)` results to `None` (because the `print` function returns nothing), so nothing is printed. However, the `print` function itself printed the `None`.

I honestly didn't read your code, but here's a function that takes a string with code and produces the same output as the interpreter would:

```
def interactive(code):
    try:
        result = eval(code)
        if result is not None:
            print(repr(result))
    except SyntaxError:
        exec(code)
```

Comment: "The interpreter prints out repr(result) only if result is not None."

I had read that, and then decided it wasn't true when I saw the behavior of "print(None)"... even though you're right, it's the print() function itself printing the None there, and that's so obvious in hindsight.

Not sure why I got so hopelessly confused here; thanks for putting me back on the right track.