# How to properly interpret a single line of python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, eval, interpreter

I need to execute a line of python code that is entered by the user.
If it is a statement I want to execute it, but if it is an expression, I want the result to be returned and do some fancy stuff with it.
The problem is that python has two different functions for that, namely `exec` and `eval`.

Currently I just try to evaluate the string that the user entered.
If that raises a SyntaxError, this may indicate that the string is an statement instead, so I try to execute it.

```
try:
    result = eval(command, scope)
except SyntaxError:
    # Probably command is a statement, not an expression
    try:
        exec(command, scope)
    except Exception as e:
        return command + ' : ' + str(e)
except Exception as e:
    return command + ' : ' + str(e)
else:
    pass # Some fancy stuff
```

This feels rather hacky. Is there a neater, more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Blindly executing user-supplied code is a dangerous game.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that.  But I'm implementing an embedded interpreter. Notice that I supply the scope though.

Comment: Close voter: this is not opinion based. I'm asking for the pythonic way, which is a generally accepted question on this site.

Comment: You probably want [the code module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html).

Comment: @Lattyware I've looked at it and I'm not sure how. It seems that those functions do extra stuff like printing the eval result, which is not what I want.

Comment: What if the "line" provided is not something that will involve just one line? Like "if a == b:" ? Control question, what happens if you try to evaluate a statement?? (I don't know the answer to the latter question)

Comment: I would probably do `_code = code.compile_command(user_input)` and then check `if _code is None` but there might be a better way.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  If you try to evaluate a statement you'll get a SyntaxError. That's why I specifically catch a SyntaxError in the question code.

Answer (score 4):

While I think your existing code is probably reasonably Pythonic (under the doctrine that it's "easier to ask forgiveness than permission"), I suspect the best alternative approach is to use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module to inspect the code in your string:

```
tree = ast.parse(some_input_string)
if len(tree.body) == 1 and isinstance(tree.body[0], ast.Expr):
    result = eval(some_input_string, scope)
else:
    exec(some_input_string, scope)
    result = None
```

Note that some common statements are really "expression statements". So, an input string like `'do_stuff("args")'` will use the `eval` branch of the code above, rather than the `exec` branch. I don't think this will have any adverse consequences, but you never know.

It is also possible to compile the `tree` that has been parsed and then pass the result into the `eval` or `exec` calls later. I found it rather fiddly to get right though (you need to wrap the `ast.Expr`'s `value` attribute in an `ast.Expression` in the top branch) and so I went with the simpler (to read and understand) alternative of just passing in the string and letting Python parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the try-except a bit. There's no real context in your example, but assuming you want to be able to execute `a=1` and then evaluate `a` afterwards and get `1`, then you could do something like...

```
from code import InteractiveConsole
interpreter = InteractiveConsole()

def run(code):

    try: return eval(code.strip(), interpreter.locals)
    except: pass

    try: interpreter.runcode(code)
    except Exception as error: return error
```

This should work for more than one line of code too.

Without knowing a bit more about your objective it's difficult to say how to do it best, but what you have is fine in principle, it just needs tidying up. This similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248814/1253428) includes a minimal version of the same try-except logic again, with a focus on mimicking the interpreter more faithfully.

Answer (score 0):

you missed one, actually there are *three* functions related to executing code, and the one you missed is [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#compile).

`compile()` takes three required arguments, the code to be compiled, the name of the module being compiled, which will appear in tracebacks originating from that code, and a "mode".  The mode argument should be one of "exec", for compiling whole modules, "eval" for compiling simple expressions, and "single", which should be a single line of interactive input!

In all three cases, you pass the returned `code` object to `eval`, with the desired context:

```
>>> c = compile("if 1 < 2:\n    print(3)", "<string>", "single")
>>> eval(c)
3
>>>
```

Comment: Note that `eval` is returning `None` in your example, not `3`. The `3` is being displayed because of the `print` call.

Comment: indeed, even simple expressions, will "return" `None` when compiled with "single", but will invoke `sys.displayhook`.

Comment: As explained in the question, when evaluating an expression, I need the result to be returned, not printed. So even when you use `compile`, still the decision has to be made whether to pass 'exec' or 'eval'.